# How to exit after catching a Ctrl+C?

Tags: perl, signals, exit

After I've caught a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to do a cleanup is it more correct to exit the program with `kill( 'INT', $$ )` than exit the program with `exit()`?

Comment: What gave you that idea? Why should that be "more correct"?

Comment: Because as far as I know, that is what Ctrl+C would have done if I hadn't caught it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> sends the `INT` signal to your process. Sending another `INT` after handling that is useless:

```
perl -E'$SIG{INT}=sub{say "interrupted"; $c++ < 5 and kill INT => $$}; <>'
```

This is an unusual way to implement <del>recursion</del> gotos, but no amount of `^C ^C ^C` will terminate the program. (Press enter to exit).

If you want to `exit` the program, do just that (preferably with non-zero status).

---

Relevant quote from `perlmod`:

> An `END` code block is executed as late as possible, that is, after perl has finished running the program and just before the interpreter is being exited, even if it is exiting as a result of a `die()` function.  (But not if it's morphing into another program via `exec`, or being blown out of the water by a signal—you have to trap that yourself (if you can).

I.e. the self-interrupting `kill INT => $$` would not execute `END` blocks by default. This probably stems from the “make difficult things possible” philosophy. Unless certain exit operations can take very long time to run, you should still perform them on `INT` or `TERM` signals. If users whish immediate shutdown, there still is `KILL`.

Comment: Before the `kill( 'INT', $$ )` I would have set $SIG{INT} back to "DEFAULT".

Comment: @sid_com Ok, in that case it's all about whether you want to run `END` blocks or not. There are few reasons not to, so an `exit` still is preferable.